# Assistance with splitting a line from a csv

Tags: java, csv, split

As the title says I'm running into an issue trying to split a line from a csv file. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    FileReader fr=new FileReader("1-1-16.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line=br.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        line.split(",");
        newList.add(line);
        line=br.readLine();
        }
    newList.remove(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
```

Here is my output:

```
218.213.0.0,218.213.255.255,China,Hong Kong,Com Asia Ltd.
124.202.108.0,124.202.159.255,China,Beijing,Beijing Province Network
185.7.35.0,185.7.35.126,Luxemborg,Luxemborg,NETBRELLA CORPORATION
```

I need to split the line to make it easier for me to retrieve the starting and ending IP addresses however line.split(",") doesn't seem to work; any advice?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what "doesn't seem to work" means?

Comment: Your `line.split(",")` effectively does **nothing**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing newList.add(line). This adds the original un-split line to the list.

Do something like:

```
String[] lines = line.split(",");
newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(lines));
```

Comment: This solved it. I looked around and saw to do String[] varname = line.split(","); but when i implemented it i was getting the runaround of newList.add not working so try addall which also didnt work. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `line` have the string `218.213.0.0,218.213.255.255,China,Hong Kong,Com Asia Ltd.`, and you are trying to get the IP addresses out of it, you can try the below code.

```
 String[] spl = line.split(",");
 String ip1 = spl[0];
 String ip2 = spl[1];
```